# WebStorm: Argument type this is not assignable to parameter type ObjectConstructor

Tags: typescript, webstorm

When I use the following constructor in TypeScript, I get the error Argument type this is not assignable to parameter type ObjectConstructor. But CLI is not showing the error. The code looks OK to me ([syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)). Is this a false error?

```
export class Store{
  oid: string;
  storeNumber: string;
  address: string;

  public constructor(init?: Partial<Store>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }
}
```

Comment: I experienced same issue. When I switched to VSCode, no error. Looks like webstorm issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been logged as a [WebStorm bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36766). (Thank you, [@lena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274212/lena)).

Until a fix is issued, one could supress the inspection by placing the following comment above the line containing the false positive:

```
// noinspection TypeScriptValidateTypes
```